# How do I concisely return the first result in a Code Igniter query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to return an object representing a journal retrieved based on its ID in a model.

```
public function getJournal($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM journals WHERE id='$id'");
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? ($query->result())[0] : NULL;
}
```

However, PHP issues an error declaring an unexpected open right bracket ([).

I ended up actually looping through the array of 1 object entity to return it, which is silly but works.

```
public function getJournal($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM journals WHERE id='$id'");
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $journal)
            return $journal;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

What is a more concise way to return this object?

Comment: `array_pop()` (last element) or `current()` (first element). you can also use `reset()` to jump to the first element and return it, if you arn't sure about the array's internal reference pointer's position.

Comment: Don't use `array_pop()`--it's destructive.  `end()` is `current()`'s counterpart.  Regardless, use the DB driver's methods to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of grabbing the `result()`, just use the `row()` method:

```
$first_result = $query->row();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function getJournal($id)
{
    return $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('journals')->row() ?: NULL; // (requires PHP 5.3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should limit your query to 1:

```
SELECT * FROM journals WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1
```

Secondly, the reason it was stating that there was an unexpected open right bracket. This is because the result method in codeigniter returns an object and not an array. You could use `->result_array();` if you want that... but if you decided to limit to 1, you could just as well return the object...

Good luck

Comment: You could use the row_array() method to return the first row only as an array (equivalent to the row() / results() for objects)

Comment: and user1276505's row() method is a good way to get the actual result from the object. keep in mind it also returns the object, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getJournal($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM journals WHERE id = $id limit 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->row();
    }
    return NULL;
}
```